# How to minimize our Activity on and show it as a floating Button?

Tags: android

I need to know the name of the widget by which minimize and maximize our activity on the same screen ....like in youtube and music players..

I have already tried to search on Youtube and google but couldn't find it..

Comment: This can you achieve by foreground services

Comment: The only meaning of "Minimizing an Activity" is: "close/pause it". When it is "minimized" you have to start a BackgroundService that will create and then show a floating View previously manually added to the WindowManager.

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. You may be referring to the effect by which a YouTube video shrinks as you navigate to/from the home page and expands when you tap it, but from your question it isn't clear.